# Embed posting of social networks with Ionic Framework and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, ionic-framework, instagram

I am having a problem when wanting to embed a post from Twitter, Instagram or Vine with Ionic Framework, all social networks using Blockquote to display the content, look bad, do not show all the elements nor display the correct styles...

This is the code in Twitter:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p>Web designers life by <a href="https://twitter.com/Monish_bansal">@Monish_bansal</a> CC <a href="https://twitter.com/CsharpCorner">@CsharpCorner</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/webdeveloper?src=hash">#webdeveloper</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/webdevelopment?src=hash">#webdevelopment</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/developers?src=hash">#developers</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/programmers?src=hash">#programmers</a> <a href="http://t.co/inTkoRpJ0k">pic.twitter.com/inTkoRpJ0k</a></p>&mdash; C# Corner (@CsharpCorner) <a href="https://twitter.com/CsharpCorner/status/560759820731445249">January 29, 2015</a></blockquote>
```

This is in Vine:

```
<iframe src="https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT/embed/postcard" width="300" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe><script src="https://platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js"></script>
```

And this is in Instagram:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="4" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://instagram.com/p/0YwbCVpsq_/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_top">Tarde de proyectorista #cine #ushuaia #packewaia #proyector</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">A photo posted by @gabfiocchi on <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2015-03-18T23:04:25+00:00">Mar 18, 2015 at 4:04pm PDT</time></p></div></blockquote>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need run code after DOM  onload:

`window['twttr'].widgets.load();` - **for twitter**

`window['instgrm'].Embeds.process({hidecaption:false});` - **insta**

if it is cordova app then should add "http://" to src in index.html

```
<script async defer src="http://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
<script async defer src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```